# Verificação de senha criptografada

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, stored-procedures

Estou com uma dificuldade de fazer a verificação de login no `Delphi` com senha criptografada no banco `MySQL`, eu consigo fazer o cadastro 
e criptografar a senha no banco de dados através do `Delphi` com a `StoredProcedure` que criei no `MySQL`, essa criptografia fiz através da função `MD5` do proprio `MySQL`. No `Delphi`, uso `TSQLStoredProc` para utilizar a `StoredProcedure` do banco de dados.

A dificuldade está na `Function` que criei no `Mysql`, ela retorna um inteiro. Caso seja `zero` o retorno:

`o login está incorreto`

Caso seja `um`:

```
o login está certo
```

A `Function` funciona corretamente no `MySQL`, faz a comparação correta, porem, o que não sei é como faço para mostrar ou comparar essa `Function` com esse retorno de inteiro no `Delphi`.

Aqui esta meu código para que entendam:

SQL:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` ( 
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL, 
  `firstlast_name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)$$ 
 DELIMITER ; 

 DELIMITER $$  
 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fun_valida_usuario`$$  
 CREATE FUNCTION `fun_valida_usuario`(p_username VARCHAR(15)  
                , p_password VARCHAR(45) ) RETURNS INT(1)  
 BEGIN  
 DECLARE _ret            INT(1) DEFAULT 0;  
     SET _ret = IFNULL((SELECT DISTINCT 1  
                       FROM tbl_users  
                      WHERE `username` = p_username  
                       AND `password` = MD5(p_password)),0);                            
 RETURN _ret;  
 END$$  
 DELIMITER ; 

DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_iae_tbl_users`( 
p_opc varchar(1), 
p_id int, 
p_username varchar(15), 
p_firstlast_name varchar(80), 
p_password varchar(45)) 
BEGIN 

IF ((p_opc = 'I') && (p_username != '') && (p_password != '')) THEN 

  INSERT INTO tbl_users (id, username, firstlast_name, `password`) VALUES (p_id, p_username, p_firstlast_name, MD5(p_password)); 

ELSE 

IF ((p_opc = 'E') && (p_id > 0)) THEN 

   delete from tbl_users where id = p_id; 

ELSE 

IF ((p_opc = 'A')) THEN 

  UPDATE tbl_users set id = p_id, username = p_username, firstlast_name = p_firstlast_name, `password` = p_password WHERE id = p_id; 

ELSE 
SELECT 'Você não pode realizar as alterações' AS Msg; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
END IF; 

END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

PAS:

```
unit Unit1; 

interface 

uses 
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, 
  Dialogs, WideStrings, DBXMySql, DB, SqlExpr, FMTBcd, Provider, DBClient, 
  StdCtrls, Mask, DBCtrls; 

type 
  TForm1 = class(TForm) 
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection; 
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet; 
    DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider; 
    SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery; 
    SQLQuery1id: TIntegerField; 
    SQLQuery1username: TStringField; 
    SQLQuery1firstlast_name: TStringField; 
    SQLQuery1password: TStringField; 
    DataSource1: TDataSource; 
    ClientDataSet1id: TIntegerField; 
    ClientDataSet1username: TStringField; 
    ClientDataSet1firstlast_name: TStringField; 
    ClientDataSet1password: TStringField; 
    InsertUser: TButton; 
    Edit1: TEdit; 
    Edit2: TEdit; 
    proc_iae_tbl_users: TSQLStoredProc; 
    proc_iae_tbl_usersMsg: TStringField; 
    Edit3: TEdit; 
    Edit4: TEdit; 
    Edit5: TEdit; 
    VerifyLogin: TButton; 
    Label1: TLabel; 
    Label2: TLabel; 
    SQLStoredProc1: TSQLStoredProc; 
    SQLStoredProc1Value: TIntegerField; 
    Label3: TLabel; 
    DBEdit1: TDBEdit; 
    DataSource2: TDataSource; 
    SQLQuery2: TSQLQuery; 
    SQLQuery2Valor: TIntegerField; 
    Label4: TLabel; 
    DBEdit2: TDBEdit; 
    DataSource3: TDataSource; 
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject); 
  private 
    { Private declarations } 
  public 
    { Public declarations } 
  end; 

var 
  Form1: TForm1; 

implementation 

{$R *.dfm} 

procedure TForm1.InsertUserClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
   proc_iae_tbl_users.Close; 
   proc_iae_tbl_users.ParamByName('p_opc').Value:= 'I'; 
   proc_iae_tbl_users.ParamByName('p_username').Value:= Edit1.Text; 
   proc_iae_tbl_users.ParamByName('p_firstlast_name').Value:= Edit2.Text; 
   proc_iae_tbl_users.ParamByName('p_password').Value:= Edit3.Text; 
   proc_iae_tbl_users.ExecProc; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.VerifyLoginClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
   // Aqui deve ficar o código para logar e verificar o login 
end; 

end.
```

Alguem pode me dar uma solução?

Agradeço sua disposição desde já. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

### Algumas considerações sobre segurança

De acordo com o que você descreveu, sugiro que verifique os seguintes tópicos:

1. Não mande a sua senha para ser criptografada no banco. Durante esse processo qualquer um ouvindo a sua interação com ele pode descobrir a senha. Mesmo que você tenha alguma medida de segurança na camada de transporte, é 1000% mais seguro criptografar no cliente(Delphi).
2. MD5 não é um bom algoritmo de encriptação. Como ele é calculado muito rapidamente, um atacante pode calcular bilhões de hashes por segundo. Considere usar SHA-1 ou preferencialmente SHA-2.

### Dito isso, a resposta da pergunta

`TSQLStoredProc` herda do componente `TDataset`. Ou seja ele é um dataset. Portanto tudo o que você precisa para consumir o resultado de uma stored procedure é abrir o dataset e usar os seus valores. Exemplo:

```
StoredProc.Open;
try
    CredenciaisValidas := StoredProc.FieldByName('Result').AsInteger = 1;
finally
    StoredProc.Close;
```

Obs.: Não me recordo se `Result` é o nome  campo usado para o retorno de funções, mas nada que um pouco de debug não resolva ;)

Comment: Nossa, faz muito sentido suas considerações. Vou começar abordar elas. Enquanto TStoredProc, usei somente para realizar o CRUD, porque tenho uma procedure no banco pra isso. E para logar, usei TSQLQuery, porque tenho que passar um SQL e nesse SQL tem que estar os TEdit de usuário e senha. Se tem como fazer com TStoredProc eu não sei :/ Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Então galera, de tanto tentar, consegui resolver.

No meu botão de logar, implementei o seguinte código:

```
  DM.sql_login.Close;
  DM.sql_login.SQL.Clear;
  DM.sql_login.SQL.Add('SELECT fun_valida_usuario("'+edt_username.Text+'","'+edt_password.Text+'") AS Ret');
  DM.sql_login.Open;

  if (DM.sql_login['Ret'] = 1 ) then
    begin
       DM.sql_login.Close;
      Close;
    end
  else
    begin
      MessageBox(handle,'Usuário ou Senha estão incorretos','Aviso',mb_IconError + mb_OK);
    end;
```

Espero que ajude alguem que esteja com a mesma dúvida. Obrigado quem leu.

Comment: Eu não reparei que você já tinha respondido! De qualquer forma de uma olhada nas considerações sobre segurança que eu descrevi na minha resposta....